# R Regex searching text between delimiter

Tags: r, regex

I have a data file which has text in the following format:

> "name: alex  age: 27 profession: it"

I want to pull the data between ':' (it should exclude the preceding field name before ":" e.g. name, age, and profession are the only corresponding values that should be retrieved. The token names are not same; they can change.)

I want data to be

> alex 27 it

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: have a look at `stringr::str_split`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsub` to match word (`\\w+`), then a `:`, one or more spaces (`\\s+`) followed by a word captured as a group (`(\\w+)`) and replace it with the backreference.

```
gsub("\\w+:\\s+(\\w+)", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "alex 27 it"
```

NOTE: Here, we assume the pattern of the string is in `key: value` pair

Answer (score 0):

Using str_split with a negative lookback Regex can you split the text into a vector of three

```
st <- "name: alex age: 27 profession: it"
str_split(st,"(?<!:) ")
```

after that it is easy to remove the text that we dont want with gsub

```
str_split(st,"(?<!:) ") %>% unlist() %>% gsub("^.*: ","",.)
```

now using the same technic but extracting the names and using setNames we get a named list wich is very  comfortable to work with

```
dta <- setNames(
    str_split(st,"(?<!:) ") %>% 
        unlist() %>% 
        gsub("^.*: ","",.) %>% 
        as.list(),
    str_split(st,"(?<!:) ") %>% 
        unlist() %>% 
        gsub(":.*$","",.))


 dta$profession
[1] "it"
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `str_extract_all` from `stringr`. This matches alphanumerics (`[[:alnum:]]`) that are followed by a `:` and a space (`\\s`) and ends at a word boundary (`\\b`):

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(string, "(?<=:\\s)[[:alnum:]]+\\b")[[1]]
# [1] "alex" "27"   "it"
```

or:

```
paste(str_extract_all(string, "(?<=:\\s)[[:alnum:]]+\\b")[[1]], collapse = " ")
# [1] "alex 27 it"
```

Comment: No solution is  working the second field data is not always number it can be character also

Comment: @hari sorry, I dont understand your point. How is my solution not working? It would match any alphanumeric characters that are followed by a colon and space.